# Regex (python) to match same group several times only when preceded or followed by specific pattern

Tags: python, regex

Suppose I have the following text:

```
Products to be destroyed: «Prabo», «Palox 2000», «Remadon strong» (Rule). The customers «Dilora» and «Apple» has to be notified.
```

I need to match every string within the «» quotes but ONLY in the period starting with the "Products to be destroyed:" pattern or ending with the (Rule) pattern.

In other words in this example I do NOT want to match Dilora nor Apple.

The regex to get the quoted contents in the capturing group is:

```
«(.+?)»
```

Is it possible to "anchor" it to either a following pattern (such as Rule) or even to a prior pattern (such as "Products to be destroyed:"?

This is my [saved attempt](https://regex101.com/r/JachmY/1) on regex101

Thank you very much.

Comment: Extract with `Products to be destroyed:\s*(«[^«»]*»(?:[\s,]+«[^«»]*»)*)` and then split to get the chunks you need or use your current regex to extract all the chunks inside quotes.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Would `(?<=Products to be destroyed: )(«[^«»]*»(?:[\s,]+«[^«»]*»)*)|(«[^«»]*»(?:[\s,]+«[^«»]*»)*)(?= \(Rule)` be needed to  account for "in the period starting with the "Products to be destroyed:" pattern **or** ending with the (Rule) pattern."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match at least a single part between the arrows, and when there is a match, extract all the parts using re.findall for example.

The example data seems to be within a dot. In that case you can match at least a single arrow part matching any char except a dot using a negated character class.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hHJMMp/1) for at least a single match, and [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/UCEhg7/1) to match the separate parts afterwards

```
import re

regex = r"\bProducts to be destroyed:[^.]*«[^«»]*»[^.]*\."
s = 'Products to be destroyed: «Prabo», «Palox 2000», «Remadon strong» (Rule). The customers «Dilora» and «Apple» has to be notified.'
result = re.search(regex, s)

if result:
    print(re.findall(r"«([^«»]*)»", result.group()))
```

Output

```
['Prabo', 'Palox 2000', 'Remadon strong']
```

Comment: Does this account for "or ending with the (Rule) pattern"?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I don't know what rule is, it could as well be the dot or a string before it? It would be nice if it was `\(Rule\)`

Comment: I interpret it as the existence of the string "(Rule)"

Comment: @MonkeyZeus You might write it like this `\bProducts to be destroyed:(?:(?!\(Rule\)).)*?«[^«»]*».*?\(Rule\)` https://regex101.com/r/KOkY80/1 You can also post your solution.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus If there are consecutive arrow parts, then Wiktor's pattern would be a better option to prevent some backtracking and match the data format.

Comment: Thank a lot. Will study to understand how it works :)